# error multiple methods named zIndex found with mismatched results

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am not sure how to rewrite this code to avoid compiler confusion. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. ZIndex is the method flagged in the error message.

```
(void)stackByZIndexIn:(UIView *)container {
  NSArray *sorted =
  [container.subviews sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id view1,
      id view2) {
   int z1 = [view1 respondsToSelector:@selector(zIndex)] ? [view1 zIndex] : 0;

   int z2 = [view2 respondsToSelector:@selector(zIndex)] ? [view2 zIndex] : 0;
    if (z1 > z2) {
      return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if (z1 < z2) {
      return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
  }];
```

Comment: What confusion are you getting, as your code looks reasonable?  Also are you sure the `subviews` aren't already in the correct `zIndex` order by default?

Comment: zIndex isn't a property on UIView, so it would be helpful if you posted your class code which contains zIndex. It sounds like you might have a property and a method both named zIndex or something along those lines

Comment: One option would be to cast `view1` and `view2` to the actual class that has the proper `zIndex` method.

Comment: The last part of the error messages reads "parameter type or attributes" . I will look and see if ZIndex is defined as a property. I do have zindex defined as a property in other parts of the code. I thought that ZIndex and Zindex would be seen as different(Totally sloppy I know.) Maybe I made an error there

Comment: what would the statement look like if view1 was cast as an int?

Comment: I found the problem.Alex nailed it. I had used ZIndex as a property. Thank you for all the help. Now it is time to clean up all my sloppy code.

Comment: Ah no problem! It happens :)